# Где взять для компиляции nginx модуль ngx_http_upstream_module

Tags: nginx, компиляция

Пытаюсь скомпилировать из исходников nginx в том числе с модулем mod_zip-1.1.6, при компиляции ругается

```
implicit declaration of function ‘ngx_http_upstream_header_variable’
```

Я так понимаю, что ему не хватает модуля ngx_http_upstream_module. Всё обыскал, не нашел где взять его сорсы, чтобы подсунуть в компиляцию nginx. Как решить проблему?

Компилирую следующим образом.
Распаковал nginx и модули, расположил всё в одной папке. 
Захожу в директорию nginx.
Выполняю:

```
./configure --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-openssl=/root/nginx_source/openssl-1.0.1t --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-file-aio --add-module=/root/nginx_source/nginx-push-stream-module-0.4.1 --add-module=/root/nginx_source/headers-more-nginx-module-0.33 --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic'
```

Затем выполняю make, вот тут то и выдаёт ошибку указанную выше.

Comment: Откуда исходники? Откуда mod_zip? Как компилируете?

Comment: Исходники nginx с их офф сайта. mod_zip вот отсюда https://github.com/evanmiller/mod_zip
Уже сталкивался с этой проблемой, но решить так и не удалось, пришлось отказаться от mod_zip, но в этот раз хочется побороть.

Comment: А третий вопрос?

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл, добавил в описание.

Comment: Ну, вообще-то это встроенный модуль который собирается всегда. https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/d817ceae729914e7423c4c206165fc244513f021/src/http/ngx_http_upstream.c#L167
Минимальная сборка вида `./auto/configure --add-module=../mod_zip; make` у меня сработала. Я вижу, что у вас ещё другие модули подключаются. Попробуйте без них